# create a Command Button to copy and paste data in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below (found on the intrnet) to copy and paste a row when a button is clicked in Excel.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xSheet.Name <> "Definitions" And xSheet.Name <> "fx" And xSheet.Name <> "Needs" Then
            xSheet.Range("A1:C17 ").Copy
            xSheet.Range("J1:L17").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How can i modify this code to copy the data from sheet named "input" to another sheet named "list" ?

Also, how can I ship a row everytime the SUBMIT button is pressed?

And one last question; one of the cells includes a =NOW() function. When using the code above to copy and paste the data, this cell is showing garbage data. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What do you mean with "ship a row everytime the SUBMIT" ?
What do you define as "garbage" data, does it show #N/A or incorrect value?

Answer (score 0):

use `Worksheets` object to access wanted sheet by its name

and since you're interestd in values only, then you can use `Value` property of `Range` objects:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Worksheets("list").Range("J1:L17").Value = Worksheets("input").Range("A1:C17").Value
End Sub
```